# Why is sp_executesql so slow with parameters?

Tags: sql-server

We had a sql query that was executed from the C# layer against SQL Server 2012 using sp_executesql.  Here is a simplified example of what this looked like when run.

```
exec sp_executesql N'
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = @MyParameter
'
,N'@MyParameter int'
,@MyParameter=1
```

For reasons not fully understood, this query took 4 minutes to run.  We changed the query by copying all input parameters to local variables, and then only using the variables in the query, and the execution time went down to 0 seconds.

```
exec sp_executesql N'
declare @MyVariable int = @MyParameter
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = @MyVariable
'
,N'@MyParameter int'
,@MyParameter=1
```

Does anyone understand why this happens?  More importantly, what can be done about it, without having to change my code?  Surely, this is an indication that something is wrong with the SQL Server installation and can be changed by modifying some database settings.  So far, this has only been an issue in one environment, of many, with one particular query, but I am afraid that it is going to crop up more, as we have a lot of queries that use parameters in this way.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the Execution Plan for these operations?  It may provide some insight into what the engine is doing differently in these two scenarios

Comment: Did you run it immediately after?  Did you clear the database cache and before?  It might be that your second is running faster because it's already created a query plan etc. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/23/sql-server-stored-procedure-clean-cache-and-clean-buffer/

Comment: Parameter Sniffing and Plan Caches, look at the Query Plans

Comment: Yep parameter sniffing.   See here:   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html